# Browsers now ignore HTML encoded ampersands?

Tags: html

The conventional wisdom I keep seeing is that ampersands for user facing text and hrefs and such in HTML need to be encoded so that they don't mess up the parsing of the HTML. I also see conflicting advice that HTML 5 has now loosened the necessity of these conventions so that you can just pass something like

```
<a href="somepage.html?x=1&y=2">...</a>
```

and it will render just fine.

I've been seeing that when I write the HTML with the encoded ampersands like

```
<a href="somepage.html?x=1&amp;y=2">...</a>
```

, modern browsers like Chrome, Safari, Firefox, treat the encoded string literally. When I click on that href, those browsers will take me to the URL somepage.html?x=1&amp;y=2 instead of the URL somepage.html?x=1&y=2.

This has been breaking the functionality of some external links. Let's say I embed an external link in my website to an audio asset like an MP3 for some on demand music that belongs to some 3rd party provider I don't control. When I put it unencoded like `somepage.html?x=1&y=2`, the browser takes me to the URL `somepage.html?x=1&y=2` and the MP3 downloads just fine. When I put it encoded like `somepage.html?x=1&amp;amp;y=2`, the browser takes me to the URL `somepage.html?x=1&amp;amp;y=2` and the MP3 does not download at all. The website that the link belongs to gives back a blank response.

Why are these browsers ignoring the encoded ampersands and treating the href string literally? Does this mean we *really* don't need to encode ampersands any more for links? Now it's safe to just put links in hrefs as-is? In that regard, is it possible that nowadays, HTML encoding ampersands can actually be detrimental to the functioning of a website like in the example of the MP3 from some 3rd party provider?

Comment: What you are talking about is URIs but HTML and browsers have nothing to do with that specification. Sorry I don't have more time.

Comment: "Does this mean we really don't need to encode ampersands any more for links?"  You never needed to do this in a URI (and doing so never worked.)  `&amp;` is an HTML encoding, not a URI encoding.

Comment: @DanielBeck: But he's putting the URI in HTML, so he does need to.

Comment: @SLaks I deleted my answer because you have me paranoid that maybe there's some old history here I'm forgetting; but just tested (with both html5 and html4 doctypes) and every browser I've tried seems to treat urls with `&amp;` identically to urls with unencoded `&`. As far as I can recall it's never been necessary to html-encode the param delimiters in a link or src URL.

Comment: It has always worked this way. Browsers have always attempted to fix it if you didn't properly encode it, but any HTML validator since the 1990s would complain about it. This behavior hasn't changed.

Comment: Yikes, I stand corrected; I guess I've been doing this wrong for the past couple of decades: http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp  (Not exactly a definitive-looking source but found it linked from an html validator)